# why funtion return type is not considered for overloading in c++?

Tags: c++

I know that we we call an overloaded function, compiler tries to match exact prototype and then goes for type promotion. But we it comes to return type, compiler does not goes for exact match and throws error.  I am not sure the logic behind it. Dear friends, can u please help me here? Thanks in advance to all

Comment: @itendra Yadav Because it is impossible having a function call to determine what tthe overloaded function shall return.

Comment: `int n=func();` -- here, `func()` can return a `double` or a `float`. Which one of these hypothetical overloads should be used, and why?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The same thing you'd do for `func(1)`, when available overloads are `func(double)` and `func(float)` - emit an error.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The linked question asks *if* return type is taken into account and the answers just say "no" and offer some ways to get a similar effect to that. This question asks *why* that is the case, and no answers to the linked question answer that.

Comment: You can ignore the returned value, and enforcing that you don’t goes against the C roots of C++.

Comment: The answer is simply because the language doesn't support it. You would have to either ask the language committee why they never implemented it, or find a rejected proposal for this feature which may contain an explanation for why it was rejected. Probably it was because the feature would be technically challenging for compiler implementers.

Comment: Let's say you had `float func();` and `std::string func();`, when you call `std::cout << func() << "\n";` which should be called?  You could clarify that with `std::cout << static_cast<std::string()>(func()) << "\n";` ... but maybe the C++ luminaries thought that would be a poor cost/benefit, and can be solved with `float func_float();` and `std::string func_string();`.

Answer (score 2):

The rules for C++ overloading are already very complex. Trying to take into account how the returned value is used would make them much more complex. If you try to write some coherent rules for covering this, you can see how they get complex.

Sure, `int n = foo();` is pretty simple. But `bar(foo())` is quite complex. Or consider `bar() + foo()` where which `bar` is called determines what `operator+` you're invoking and thus which return types of `foo` could be supported.

And the standard would have to precisely specify how and when the compiler is required to divine appropriate return types. Otherwise code might compile on one compiler and not on another, setting painful traps.

Comment: seeing all comments, I have come to conclusion that just to reduce complexity, compiler doesn't care about return type. As same complexity and heuristics are there for function arguments too. Dear friends, thank u all for urs valuable comments.